# Turn off scientific notation and offset globally

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have been trying for several hours to globally turn off scientific notation and the offset in matplotlib. my attempt at a solution

```
import matplotlib  as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The documentation says:

> set the rcParam axes.formatter.useoffset=False to turn it off globally, or set a different formatter.

```
mpl.rcParams.formatter.useoffset = False
```

Of course this fails because there is no formatter for rcParam

```
mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter.__setattr__('set_scientific',False)
```

I am completely lost trying to do this. I have just switched from matlab. So I apologize if this is very basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the setting in setting file, you can get the current setting file path by following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
print mpl.matplotlib_fname()
```

if the file is in mpl-data folder, then copy it to user setting folder by following code:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(mpl.matplotlib_fname(), mpl.get_configdir())
```

then restart you python session and show the path again:

```
print mpl.matplotlib_fname()
```

edit this file:

```
axes.formatter.useoffset      : False
```

Is you only want to disable this in one of your programm, you can set the setting before any plot:

```
mpl.rcParams["axes.formatter.useoffset"] = False
```