What Are The Y-axis "+" Signs in a pandas dataframe plot?
mode_plot = given_df.plot(kind="line", figsize=(12,4), x='Ticks', y='V_C Out', title=given_title, grid=True)
ymin = min(given_df["V_C Out"].values)
ymax = max(given_df["V_C Out"].values)
print("ymin, ymax: ", str(ymin), str(ymax))    # ymin, ymax:  2.72024 2.72088
mode_plot.plot(ylim=(ymin, ymax))


I am trying to plot a data set of voltages versus time ticks using pyplot. Even though I am trying to explicitly set the y-axis limits to be between 2.72024 and 2.72088, pyplot is instead setting the axis from 0 to 0.00088, then adding a "+2.72" label at the top of the figure.
The accuracy of the figure is correct, but I cannot find how to control this behavior. I want the y-axis values to "do the math" and not have to mentally add 2.72 to them, i.e., 2.7206
Can anyone advise? The data are as shown in the comment -> # ymin, ymax 2.72024 2.72088
Thank you.

Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/14711866/12890458 solve your question?

Not really, thanks for asking. It's of little use to have existing answers when we don't know the keywords to search. The best answer I found was here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813306/turn-off-scientific-notation-and-offset-globally

My precise implementation is this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
